# JPA - Ignore join operation in namedQuery in EclipseLink

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, eclipselink

I have below scenario

1. Entity TableA :

   ```
        @Entity
        @Table(name = "TABLE_A")
        @NamedQueries({
                @NamedQuery(name = "TableA.namedQ1", query = "SELECT t1 FROM TableA t1 JOIN FETCH t2.TableB t2"
                        + " WHERE <conditions here>"),
                @NamedQuery(<Need query here which will ignore mapping below and return rows only for TableA>)
                }   )
        public class TableA implements Serializable{

        @Id
        @Column(name = "id")
        private int id

        ...
        ...
        ...

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "tableA", cascade = CascadeType.ALL ,fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
        private List<TableB> tableB;




        }
   ```
2. Entity TableB :

   ```
        @Entity
        @Table(name = "TABLE_B")
        public class TableB implements Serializable{

        @Id
        @Column(name = "id1")
        private int id1

        ...
        ...
        ...




        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "id",insertable = false, updatable = false)
        private TableA tableA;



        }
   ```

I am facing below two issues :

1. Query mentioned above i.e

   ```
         SELECT t1 FROM TableA t1 JOIN FETCH t2.TableB t2
   ```

takes long time to execute. around 30 seconds. But the same query for same dataset takles hardly 3-4 seconds in SQL developer. ANythnig I should do in code to make it run faster?

2. I have requirement where i dont need data from other table(retrived via mapping). I would be needing data only from TableA. I tried below named query but it run separate query against TableB for each row in TableA which takes 4+ minutes to execute.

   ```
      "SELECT t1 FROM TableA t1 where <condition goes here>"
   ```

   What modifications I have to do in query to ignore mapping. I would need to retain annotations(@OneToMany) as I will need it in namedQ1.

Thanks in anticipation

Comment: If the contents of TableA is sufficient, just use a JOIN instead of a JOIN FETCH (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17431312/what-is-the-difference-between-join-and-join-fetch-when-using-jpa-and-hibernate).

Comment: @user871611 I tried mentioned post. But its firing subquery for each row in TableA

Comment: Seems like you are accessing fields from TableB. If so (and you really need the data from TableB) JOIN FETCH is your friend and your SQL client is so much faster because it's only fetching data from TableA. That would be my guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `FETCH`, you are asking to retrieve the data for the  collection in
advance. If you don't need the elements from TableB then your query should be:

```
SELECT t1 FROM TableA t1 left join t1.tableB t2
```

Note that the join is only necessary if you need to add some condition to t2.
For example:

```
SELECT t1 FROM TableA t1 left join t1.tableB t2 WHERE t2.field = 123
```

if this is not your case, than this should be enough:

```
SELECT t1 FROM TableA t1;
```

In all these cases, it will create a proxy for the collection `TableB`
and won't need to access the table on the database, unless you need to use the collection later on.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have already tried "SELECT t1 FROM TableA t1;" but it fires subquery against tableB for each row in TableA.

Comment: That can only happen if you are accessing the collection field from the retrieved elements

Comment: How do you expect it to get the data without querying the db?

Comment: Are you doing something with the `TableB` field?

Comment: I have two namedQuery.
in query one I would need to joing TableA with TableB using @OneToMany
and in second named query I want to ignore mapping.

Comment: It's clear that you need data from `TableB`, otherwise you wouldn't see that additional SQL queries. Having two named queries has nothing to do with lazy fetching.

Comment: What's happening is that after you run the named query `SELECT t1 FROM TableA t1;`, you are accessing the collection `List<TableB> tableB` from  one of the results. Because the first query didn't fetch those values, now EclipseLink needs to run additional queries to get the values. It's seems that there is something wrong with your app or that you need to load this values one way or another.

Comment: Maybe if you show us the code you are running after the query has been executed we might tell you more.

Comment: Thanks. I revisted my code and found that i was having reference made to tableB data. I removed references based on conditions and it started working as expected for me.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having similar questions

```
  Question 1 in OP : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61573091/long-time-of-fetching-data-from-oracledb-using-eclipselink

  Question 2 in OP: Solved using @Davide solution
```